# Dojo class load order

Tags: javascript, dojo

I am trying to migrate from pure javascript to Dojo and I am running into some problems. My current problem is in the order of import statements. In pure javascript I could have a file `A.js` as such

```
function(name){
    this.name=name;
}
```

And a file `B.js` as such

```
function(name,age){
    this.A=A;
    A(name);
    this.age=age;
}
```

and then I could load the two files in `index.html` either as such

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script LANGUAGE="javascript" SRC="A.js"></script>
    <script LANGUAGE="javascript" SRC="B.js"></script>
    </head>
</html>
```

or as

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script LANGUAGE="javascript" SRC="B.js"></script>
    <script LANGUAGE="javascript" SRC="A.js"></script>
    </head>
</html>
```

but if I convert `A.js` and `B.js` to dojo as such

```
dojo.declare("A", null, {
    constructor: function(name){
        this.name=name;
    }
});
```

And such

```
dojo.declare("B",[A],
    constructor:function(name,age){
        this.age=age;
    }
});
```

Then I can only load the scripts in `index.html` as such

```
<html>
    <head>
    <script LANGUAGE="javascript" SRC="A.js"></script>
    <script LANGUAGE="javascript" SRC="B.js"></script>
    </head>
</html>
```

If I try to load `B.js` before `A.js`, it will complain that `A.js` does not exist. Is there anyway around this?

Comment: really? I am using Dojo b/c of the animation functions and the inheritence structure...do tell

Comment: I can't stand that god awful `$` symbol. I find it as annoying as the `this` that gets passed around in every object parameter list of Python signatures.

Comment: puk, both toolkits are excellent, each has its own style, and depth in different areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must load A.js always before B.js

Difference between your "plain javascript code" and "Dojo" in what in "plain code" no code executed when scripts is loaded, but in "Dojo" dojo.declare() function executed immediately after B.js script is loaded (and, because script in B.js requires a class "A", that declared in "A.js", "A.js" must be loaded first for creating class "A").

Comment: is there anyway to tell a script to load other scripts? Is it like Python where everything is fair game as long as there are no circular loops? For example have the following chaining of scripts
index.html->C.js->B.js->A.js
index.html->B.js->A.js
index.html->A.js
??

Comment: I don't think dojo.require works that way. It still requires that the class it's trying to load have already been created. I can understand why too, it's because their is no correlation between scripts and dojo names. So scripts/test.js could have a class `person()` which is provided to dojo as `someone`. essentially dojo doesn't know where the script is located

Answer (score 5):

if you decided to migrate to Dojo, i propose for you [read about](http://dojocampus.org/content/2008/06/03/understanding-dojodeclare-dojorequire-and-dojoprovide/)

1. dojo.provide()
2. dojo.require()
3. dojo.declare()

The main idea of this is fallows:

**You don't need to use script tag for loading required JavaScript files.**

For example:

You have the fallowing site structure:

[image]

1. You add "dojo.js" file and put it in "Script" folder
2. You create folder "MyModules" and...
3. you create 2 own modules "ModuleA" and "ModuleB"

In your own modules you define some classes:

Code of "ModuleA":

```
dojo.provide("Scripts.MyModules.ModuleA");

dojo.declare("A", null, {
    constructor: function (name) {
        this.name = name;
    },

    sayName: function () {
        alert(this.name);
    }
});
```

Code of "ModuleB":

```
dojo.provide("Scripts.MyModules.ModuleB");
dojo.require("Scripts.MyModules.ModuleA");

dojo.declare("B", [A], {
    constructor: function (name, age) {
        this.age = age;
    },
    sayName: function () {
        alert(this.name + " " + this.age);
    }
});
```

At the beginning of each file you can see lines:

```
dojo.provide("Scripts.MyModules.ModuleA");
dojo.provide("Scripts.MyModules.ModuleB");
```

dojo.provide is an integral part of Dojo’s module system and its loader. dojo.provide() tells the loader that the a module has been provided for the given name. It also creates a JavaScript object for the name.

Also as you can see class B inherited from class A. In this case in "ModuleB" you should add this line:

```
dojo.require("Scripts.MyModules.ModuleA");
```

It means that "ModuleA" is required for "ModuleB";

And at the end, example of usages this structure on the page:

// connect dojo

```
...
<script src="Scripts/dojo.js" djconfig="parseOnLoad: true"></script>
...
```

// if you want to create object B you must connect ModuleB on page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
dojo.require("Scripts.MyModules.ModuleB");
</script>
```

// creating object B

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.addOnLoad(function () {
      var bObject = new B('John',25);
        bObject.sayName();
    });
</script>
```

**In case using of this structure you don't need care about script loading order.**

P.S. sorry for my "english"